# Query MySQL db from Python returns "Access Denied"

Tags: python, mysql

I am using

`db = MySQLdb.connect(host="machine01", user=local_settings.DB_USERNAME, passwd=local_settings.DB_PASSWORD, db=local_settings.DB_NAME)`

to connect to a DB, but I am doing this from `machine02` and I thought this would still work, but it does not. I get

`_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'test_user'@'machine02' (using password: YES)")`

as a result. However, if I simply ssh over to `machine01` and perform the same query, it works just fine. Isn't the point of `host` to be able to specify where the MySQL db is and be able to query it from any other host instead of having to jump on there to make the query?

Comment: This is indeed the point of `host`, but the server needs to accept connections from remote hosts. I would recommend checking the server configuration for this

Comment: Is the DB listening on the default port (3306)? Can you telnet from machine02 to machine01 over this port?

Comment: This seems to be the problem - I would have expected to have gotten a connection refused error, rather than just have the query take place on the wrong host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your firewall isn't blocking port 3306.

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you that '*test_user*' at machine '*machine02*' is not allowed. Probably user '*test_user*' is on '**mysql.user**' table registered with '**localhost**' as connection's host. Check it using a query like this: **select host, user from mysql.user**;

Best regards,
Oscar.